# CoCreateInstance for a 32 bit COM object doesn't return in Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, activex, 32-bit

I am trying to run a legacy Win32 app built with Delphi5 on Windows 10 64 bit. There are some COM objects in the form of dlls that need to be loaded at start up. However, when I try to load them, most of the time, not always though, the call in **CoCreateInstance** gets stuck indefinitely. I mean it just sits there. Sometimes, the objects are instantiated correctly and software does start up, so I believe registering isn't an issue. This only happens on Windows 10, on my WIndows 7 64 bit PC, it never happens.

I have isolated the problem CreateComObject in ComObj.pas, but this may just be misleading because in the end it is the call the CoCreateInstance that never returns.

```
function CreateComObject(const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(ClassID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result));
end;`
```

BTW, I tried setting the ThreadingModel to different values in registry but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? I would really appreciate any feedback as I am out of ideas at this time.

Comment: A short research delivered https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/ It looks like that could help

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I tried that method, but unfortunately, it didn't work in my case.

Comment: What is `CoCreateInstance` waiting on when it doesn't return?

Comment: I can't tell what it is waiting for, as the call goes to the Win32 api. This happens on more than one computer so it is likely not a computer issue.